# after changing ip address to static internet connection is missing

Tags: static-ip

I try to set ip static ip address via interface to this one 192.168.100.4 with this mask 255.255.255.0 and default route (get from route cmd) and dns ip from nmcli device show wlp1s0 | grep IP4.DNS

after doing so my internet doesnt work, i cannot open any website